# getting error / crashed when internet connection lost

Tags: vb.net

Getting error / crashed when internet connection lost in visual basic 2008.

```
Public Function GetIP() As String
    Dim uri_val As New Uri("http://example.com/")
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri_val)

    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get

    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim myIP As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    response.Close()

    Return myIP
End Function
```

Comment: And which exception / error do you get? You might want to use a `try` ... `catch` statement. And how should this work without an internet connection? Please edit your question and add the missing pieces...

Comment: A crash is an unhandled exception so you have two choices: either do something to prevent the exception or catch it. Your app can't prevent an internet connection dropping so you only have one choice. You should be using exception handling in any situation where something beyond your control may fail.